# picklist value is not populating via flow from one object to other object

Tags: picklist, flow

I have a object WSA having lookup relation with contact. Created a flow to insert record in WSA. 
Now I am trying to update contact with inserted fields data of WSA to Contact. All fields are getting copied. BUT
The marital_status__c(Picklist) field of WSA is NOT populating or copied to MArital_status__c (Picklist) field of contact. Its coming blank.

Is the issue related to picklist? How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that MArital_status__c picklist on Contact have all values from marital_status__c picklist on your other object.

Comment: Yes Both marital_Status__c have same values. and in same order. But still not copying from WSA object to Contact.

Answer (score 0):

Do you choose the configuration of variable correctly?

Because, while configuring the variable if you select **private** then Salesforce wouldn't be able to pass data into it.

Check that once...